# How to run my integration test after tomcat deployment in jenkins ?

Tags: maven, jenkins

1. I need to run my project using tomcat (tomcat deploy)
   2.After that I need do run all my integration test using jenkins

Target :
When i run my jenkins build , my project should deploy into tomcat server and run all my integration test

Answer (score 0):

In the execute shell, you enter any commands you need Jenkins to execute. The rest is setup & configuration. Please read the [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) for building a software project. It will give you some variables you can use in the shell script (such as JAVA_HOME).